# Color TD after hover

Tags: html, css

For example, I have table with 1 row and many cells in this row.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="red"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With JS I choose one cell and apply some class to it, which colors this cell. What do I need? I need color (select) cells before clicks. When I hover on last cell, for example, I need color cells between cell with `class="red"` and cell with `hover`. Something like

```
.red + :hover {
    background: green;
}
```

If I mouseenter in left side, before cell with `class="red"` the cell also needs to color between hover (include hover) and cell with some class. Can it be done only using CSS? In real situation I have many rows and many cells.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ssq8dzje/

Comment: You mean you want to highlight cell even if user has mousehover on the left or right cell?

Comment: I doubt that's possible just by using CSS on base of what I understood from your post, we have to use jQuery or Javascript to make that possible.

Comment: @Parag Bhayani Yes, highlight, thanks.

Comment: @Luntegg This is the closest I got with CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/voknhgh7/

Comment: @Midas - great solution! Your comment should be an answer :-)

Comment: @andyb The hovering works only in the right direction.. :/

Comment: @andyb It is now fully working, see my answer :)

Comment: @Midas Wow, I misread a lot of stuff, OP apparently also wants "In real situation I have many rows and many cells." So it's the the create table thing in Microsoft Office Word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS only solution is here! =D

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
}
.red {
    background: #f33 !important;
}
td:hover {
    background: #22f !important;
}

tr:hover td.red ~ td,
tr:hover td:hover ~ td {
    background: green;
}

td.red ~ td:hover ~ td,
td:hover ~ td.red ~ td,
tr:hover td.red:hover ~ td {
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="red"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is rather hackish but it works at least. It might be possible to reduce the number of selectors as well, but I'm not bothered about it for now.

Comment: Agreed, it is rather hackish but I had a feeling it was possible with only CSS :-)

Comment: I **think** there is a slightly cleaner selector for the `transparent` property. I just dropped the second line of selectors in your solution and still works - see https://jsfiddle.net/3wjrcefn/

Answer (score 4):

***Please see the Update 1 for my updated/new full answer.***

Since CSS is not a programming language and cannot handle logic, it is <s>only</s>(apparently @Midas found a way to do it in CSS alone) doable with JS.

So it's pretty much like a range thing, right? Here is the solution made with jQuery

```js
$(function(){
  var endSelection = true;
  $("td").click(function(){
    var targetTr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var thisOrder = $(this).index();
    var redOrder = $(targetTr).find(".red").index();
    targetTr.find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    targetTr.find(".red, .active").removeClass("red active").addClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    targetTr.find(".red, .active").removeClass("red active");
    if (endSelection) {
      console.log("start selection: " + redOrder + " end selection: " + thisOrder);
      endSelection = false;
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("red");
      endSelection = true;
    }
  });
  $("td").hover(function(){
    if (endSelection) {
      var targetTr = $(this).closest("tr");
      var thisOrder = $(this).index();
      var redOrder = $(targetTr).find(".red").index();
      $(targetTr).find("td").each(function(i, elem){
        if (thisOrder > redOrder) {
          if (i > redOrder && i < thisOrder)
            $(this).addClass("active");
        } else if (thisOrder < redOrder) {
          if (i < redOrder && i > thisOrder)
          $(this).addClass("active");
        }
      });
    }
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td.active").removeClass("active");
  });
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
}

td.selected {
  background: #ffaaaa;
}

td:hover {
  background: #2222ff;
}

td.active {
  background: green;
}

td.red {
  background: #ff3333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="red"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Explanation

And now to explain the highlighting, the concept is simple: We will record the **index of the `td` we have our mouse on** and the **index of the `.red` td**. Then, we think of the simple logic and by using a loop, we compare `i`, `thisOrder` and `redOrder` to find which element we have to add the class `active`.

Finally, when we do a mouse out event, remove all `.active` class.

Feel free to leave a comment if you are not familiar with jQuery ;)

---

## Update 1

Apparently, I miss the text of OP wanting to have "many rows", so the result should be a "create table thing" in many word processor apps. This time, it can't be done in CSS alone because it can't backwards select.

I don't know which type you want, but I've coded the 2 in mind.

### Style 1: Rectangular shaped selection

Useful for size marking?...

```js
$(function(){
  var endSelection = true;
  $("td").click(function(){
    var targetTable = $(this).closest("table");
    var thisPos = getPosXY($(this));
    var redPos = getPosXY($($(targetTable).find(".red")));
    targetTable.find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    targetTable.find(".red, .active").removeClass("red active").addClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    targetTable.find(".red, .active").removeClass("red active");
    if (endSelection) {
      console.log(
        "startX:" + redPos.x,
        "endX:" + thisPos.x,
        "startY:" + redPos.y,
        "endY:" + thisPos.y
      );
      endSelection = false;
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("red");
      endSelection = true;
    }
  });
  function getPosXY($elem) {
    return {
      x: $elem.index(),
      y: $elem.closest("tr").index()
    }
  }
  
  $(".selection-grid td").hover(function(){
    if (endSelection) {
      var targetTable = $(this).closest("table");
      var tableH = targetTable.find("tr").eq(0).length;
      var tableW = targetTable.find("tr").eq(0).find("td").length;
      var thisPos = getPosXY($(this));
      var redPos = getPosXY(targetTable.find(".red"));
      var xPositive = false; //goes right means +
      var yPositive = false; //goes down means +
      if (thisPos.y > redPos.y) {
        yPositive = true;
      } else if (thisPos.y < redPos.y ) {
        yPositive = false;
      }
      if (thisPos.x > redPos.x) {
        xPositive = true;
      } else if (thisPos.x < redPos.x) {
        xPositive = false;
      }
      targetTable.find("td").each(function(){
        var currentPos = getPosXY($(this));
        var currentPosX = $(this).index();
        if (xPositive === true && yPositive === true) {
          if (
            currentPos.y >= redPos.y &&
            currentPos.y <= thisPos.y &&
            currentPos.x >= redPos.x &&
            currentPos.x <= thisPos.x
          ) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
          }
        } else if (xPositive === false && yPositive === false) {
          if (
            currentPos.y <= redPos.y &&
            currentPos.y >= thisPos.y &&
            currentPos.x <= redPos.x &&
            currentPos.x >= thisPos.x
          ) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
          }
        } else if (xPositive === true && yPositive === false){
          if (
            currentPos.y <= redPos.y &&
            currentPos.y >= thisPos.y &&
            currentPos.x >= redPos.x &&
            currentPos.x <= thisPos.x
          ) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
          }
        } else if (xPositive === false && yPositive === true){
          if (
            currentPos.y >= redPos.y &&
            currentPos.y <= thisPos.y &&
            currentPos.x <= redPos.x &&
            currentPos.x >= thisPos.x
          ) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
      
      
      
      
      
      /*var thisOrder = $(this).index();
      var redOrder = $(targetTr).find(".red").index();
      $(targetTr).find("td").each(function(i, elem){
        if (thisOrder > redOrder) {
          if (i > redOrder && i < thisOrder)
            $(this).addClass("active");
        } else if (thisOrder < redOrder) {
          if (i < redOrder && i > thisOrder)
          $(this).addClass("active");
        }
      });*/
    }
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).closest("table").find(".active").removeClass("active");
  });
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
}

td.selected {
  background: #ffaaaa;
}

td:hover {
  background: #2222ff;
}

td.active {
  background: green;
}

td.red {
  background: #ff3333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="selection-grid">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="red"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Style 2: Paragraph shaped selection

Useful for calendar marking and such...

```js
$(function(){
  var endSelection = true;
  $("td").click(function(){
    var targetTable = $(this).closest("table");
    var thisPos = getPosXY($(this));
    var redPos = getPosXY($($(targetTable).find(".red")));
    targetTable.find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    targetTable.find(".red, .active").removeClass("red active").addClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    targetTable.find(".red, .active").removeClass("red active");
    if (endSelection) {
      console.log(
        "startX:" + redPos.x,
        "endX:" + thisPos.x,
        "startY:" + redPos.y,
        "endY:" + thisPos.y
      );
      endSelection = false;
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("red");
      endSelection = true;
    }
  });
  function getPosXY($elem) {
    return {
      x: $elem.index(),
      y: $elem.closest("tr").index()
    }
  }
  
  $(".selection-grid td").hover(function(){
    if (endSelection) {
      var targetTable = $(this).closest("table");
      var tableH = targetTable.find("tr").eq(0).length;
      var tableW = targetTable.find("tr").eq(0).find("td").length;
      var thisPos = getPosXY($(this));
      var redPos = getPosXY(targetTable.find(".red"));
      var positive = false; //goes down  means +
      if (thisPos.y > redPos.y || thisPos.y == redPos.y && thisPos.x > redPos.x) {
        positive = true;
      } else if (thisPos.y < redPos.y || thisPos.y == redPos.y && thisPos.x < redPos.x) {
        positive = false;
      }
      targetTable.find("td").each(function(){
        var currentPos = getPosXY($(this));
        var currentPosX = $(this).index();
        if (positive === true) {
          if (
            currentPos.y > redPos.y &&
            currentPos.y < thisPos.y ||
            currentPos.y == redPos.y && redPos.y != thisPos.y && redPos.y != thisPos.y && currentPos.x > redPos.x ||
            currentPos.y == thisPos.y && redPos.y != thisPos.y && redPos.y != thisPos.y && currentPos.x < thisPos.x ||
            currentPos.y == thisPos.y && redPos.y == thisPos.y && currentPos.x > redPos.x && currentPos.x < thisPos.x
          ) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
          }
        } else if (positive === false) {
          if (
            currentPos.y < redPos.y &&
            currentPos.y > thisPos.y ||
            currentPos.y == redPos.y && redPos.y != thisPos.y && currentPos.x < redPos.x ||
            currentPos.y == thisPos.y && redPos.y != thisPos.y && currentPos.x > thisPos.x ||
            currentPos.y == thisPos.y && redPos.y == thisPos.y && currentPos.x < redPos.x && currentPos.x > thisPos.x
          ) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
      
      
      
      
      
      /*var thisOrder = $(this).index();
      var redOrder = $(targetTr).find(".red").index();
      $(targetTr).find("td").each(function(i, elem){
        if (thisOrder > redOrder) {
          if (i > redOrder && i < thisOrder)
            $(this).addClass("active");
        } else if (thisOrder < redOrder) {
          if (i < redOrder && i > thisOrder)
          $(this).addClass("active");
        }
      });*/
    }
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).closest("table").find(".active").removeClass("active");
  });
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
}

td.selected {
  background: #ffaaaa;
}

td:hover {
  background: #2222ff;
}

td.active {
  background: green;
}

td.red {
  background: #ff3333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="selection-grid">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="red"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There is now a CSS only solution in the question comments. It might be worth editing the *only doable in JS* out of your answer if you agree...

Comment: @andyb Thanks for informing me, but I don't see the solution I'm looking for after several scrolls. Can you be kind and tag me in their comment or send me the URL of that answer?

Comment: Try reloading this page. It's one of the comments at the top under the question. The demo is https://jsfiddle.net/voknhgh7/

Comment: @andyb But the green didn't show up on the left hand side, between the selected `td` and the red `td`. And I guess my HTML example wasn't the greatest as it didn't show that. I've edited the HTML part of my answer now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I see the problem with the CSS only demo. I already up-voted your solution since it does answer the question :-)

Comment: @andyb Thank you for your upvote and for helping me improve my answer by commenting and reminding me. :)

Comment: @andyb Sorry, that was the old fiddle. Here is the new one: https://jsfiddle.net/voknhgh7/2/

Comment: Good update. :) The second style would be possible in CSS if a bunch of inline divs are used instead. The first style might be possible using a pseudo element. But I wouldn't make much sense to do that in CSS really.

Comment: @Midas, with pseudo elements? How, can you briefly explain to me your concept? I want to learn some new tricks :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
$(function() {
  var countClicks = 0;

  $("td").click(function() {
    if (countClicks == 2) {
      $("td").removeClass("active start end");
      countClicks = 0;
    }
    countClicks++;
    if (countClicks == 1) {
      $(this).addClass("active start");
    } else if (countClicks == 2) {
      $(this).addClass("active end");
    }
  });

  $("td").hover(function() {
    var start = $(".start").index();
    var end = $(".end").index();
    if (start < 0 && end < 0 || start > 0 && end > 0) return;
    $("td").removeClass("red");
    var current = $(this).index();
    if (start < current)
      $("td").slice(start, current).addClass("red");
    if (start > current)
      $("td").slice(current, start).addClass("red");
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
}

td:hover {
  background: #2222ff;
}

.red,
.active {
  background: #ff3333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").mouseover(function(){
        $(".red").css("background","green");
    });
$("td").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".red").css("background","none");
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>dsadsa</td>
    <td class="red">dddd</td>
    <td>dsad</td>
    <td>dsad</td>
    <td>dsad</td>
    <td>dsad</td>
    <td>dsad</td>
    <td>dsad</td>
    <td>dsad</td>
    <td>dsad</td>
    <td>dsad</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer demo doesn't seem to work for me. I recommend adding a few words explaining how your solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the code for the exact requirement for highlighting color from class red till td hovering.
HTML

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>demo1</td>
    <td class="red inital">Demo 2</td>
    <td>Demo 3</td>
    <td>Demo 4</td>
    <td>Demo 5</td>
    <td>demo</td>
    <td>demo</td>
    <td>demo </td>
    <td>demo</td>
    <td>demo</td>
    <td>demo</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$( "table td" ).mouseover(function() {
    var redIndex = ($(this).parent('tr').find('.red')).index()+1;
  var currentIndex = $(this).index()+1;
  for(var i=redIndex;i<currentIndex;i++) {
  $('td').eq(i).addClass('red');
  }
});

$( "table td" ).mouseleave(function() {
    var redIndex = ($(this).parent('tr').find('.red').not('.initial')).index();
  $('td').removeClass('red');
  $('td').eq(redIndex).addClass('red');

  //alert(redIndex);

});

.red { background: red; }
table td { cursor: pointer; }
```

See the jsFiddle
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/0g949dmt/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have achieved using **CSS** i.e whenever a users **mouseenter** after **red class** this CSS code changes all the **td bg color** except the class red and 1st td. Same **could** be achieved for the one td before class red.

```
tr:hover > td:nth-child(1n+3):not(.red){
background: #2222ff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't Know whether this code is correct or not  
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>

    table, th, td:hover {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .mouseover{
     bgcolor:green;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table class="hoverTable">
     <tr>
      <td>Text 1B</td>
      <td  bgcolor="green">Text A</td>

      <td>Text 1C</td>


      <td>Text 2A</td>
      <td>Text 2B</td>
      <td>Text 2C</td>


      <td>Text 3A</td>
      <td>Text 3B</td>
      <td>Text 3C</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
      </tr>
    </table>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you don't know whether the code is correct, why are you proposing it as an answer? Answers like this are very likely to be downvoted so I recommend editing the answer to explain why your solution answers the question rather than just posting a wall of code, without a demo.